# Google Script Posting JSON Only Sends null

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have a little script that I am testing. All it needs to do is post some JSON to a service I wrote. I have a test page for my service and it works with the test page. I wrote the service in c# and I grabbed a sample JSON message which I hard-coded in the code below. When I send the JSON via Google Script, I have no luck. Does anyone see the issue here? Here is what I am trying:

```
function SendToRouter(message){

var data = {"message": {"Id":"22941f91-1b22-463c-a6bd-95245f8f8fe4","Sender":"lms@company.com","Recipient":"me@gmail.com","Subject":"Internet","Body":"payload here","ReceiveDate":"8/5/2013"}};  
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);


var headers = { "Accept":"application/json", 
                "Content-Type":"application/json"             
              };

var opt = {
            "contentType" : 'application/json',
            "method" : 'post',
            "headers":headers,
            "payload" :payload 
          };

var url = "http://www.site.com/Process/RouteLead";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
```

Thanks for any help on this one!
-Jeff

Comment: Did you ever get this figures out? I have the exact same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well I finally figured out the issue. The problem was not with Google Script, the problem was with my MVC code in c#. I switched over from a normal MVC controller action to a Web API controller. I did have to change my JSON data, so I am posting the corrected code for my Web API call. Hopefully this helps out others who are having issues. Note that I removed the 'message' from the JSON string.

```
var data =  {"Id":"22941f91-1b22-463c-a6bd-95245f8f8fe4","Sender":"lms@company.com","Recipient":"myemail@gmail.com","Subject":"Internet","Body":"payload here","ReceiveDate":"8/5/2013"};

var opt = {
contentType: "application/json",
method : "post",
payload : JSON.stringify(data)
};
var url = "http://mysite.com/api/Lead";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
```